# android : open chrome custom tab from fragment

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-fragments, chrome-custom-tabs

I have one Activity `MainActivity`. It contains a `ViewPager` hosting a fragment `FragmentPlaceHolder`. This fragment has a `RecyclerView`.

Now, on a click of a particular view, say button, inside a `RecyclerView` item, I want to open a chrome custom tab in new `Activity`. Can anyone help me with this one ? I am expecting a step wise implemention of `Chrome Custom tabs`.

Thanks.

Comment: but links will open in default browser I think

Comment: @VivekMishra Hope you are aware of [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Comment: As written in the link you provided

**What happens if the user doesn’t have a recent version of Chrome installed?**

We are using the ACTION_VIEW Intent, this means that by default the page will open in the system browser, or the user's default browser.

If the user has Chrome installed and it is the default browser, it will automatically pick up the EXTRAS and present a customized UI. It is also possible for another browser to use the Intent extras to provide a similar customized interface.

Does this mean web page will open like chrome in other browsers too??

Comment: and the link you provided has demo projects too . Try them also

Comment: Okay.. I am on it.. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, I did it this way:

First of all, add this following dependency in `build.gradle(app)`:

> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'

First create an activity `WebviewActivity`:

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "extra.url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setTitle(url);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now, say on button click you want to open chrome custom tab and load `www.google.com`, so, do it as below:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
    CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(
        this,// activity
        customTabsIntent,
        Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"), 
        new WebviewFallback()
    );

}
```

**activity_webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".helpers.WebviewActivity" />
```

Then, simply craete the classes as below:

**CustomTabActivityHelper.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsSession;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * This is a helper class to manage the connection to the Custom Tabs Service.
 */
public class CustomTabActivityHelper implements ServiceConnectionCallback {
    private CustomTabsSession mCustomTabsSession;
    private CustomTabsClient mClient;
    private CustomTabsServiceConnection mConnection;
    private ConnectionCallback mConnectionCallback;

    /**
     * Opens the URL on a Custom Tab if possible. Otherwise fallsback to opening it on a WebView.
     *
     * @param activity         The host activity.
     * @param customTabsIntent a CustomTabsIntent to be used if Custom Tabs is available.
     * @param uri              the Uri to be opened.
     * @param fallback         a CustomTabFallback to be used if Custom Tabs is not available.
     */
    public static void openCustomTab(Activity activity,
                                     CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent,
                                     Uri uri,
                                     CustomTabFallback fallback) {
        String packageName = CustomTabsHelper.getPackageNameToUse(activity);

        //If we cant find a package name, it means theres no browser that supports
        //Chrome Custom Tabs installed. So, we fallback to the webview
        if (packageName == null) {
            if (fallback != null) {
                fallback.openUri(activity, uri);
            }
        } else {
            customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(packageName);
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unbinds the Activity from the Custom Tabs Service.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that is connected to the service.
     */
    public void unbindCustomTabsService(Activity activity) {
        if (mConnection == null) return;
        activity.unbindService(mConnection);
        mClient = null;
        mCustomTabsSession = null;
        mConnection = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates or retrieves an exiting CustomTabsSession.
     *
     * @return a CustomTabsSession.
     */
    public CustomTabsSession getSession() {
        if (mClient == null) {
            mCustomTabsSession = null;
        } else if (mCustomTabsSession == null) {
            mCustomTabsSession = mClient.newSession(null);
        }
        return mCustomTabsSession;
    }

    /**
     * Register a Callback to be called when connected or disconnected from the Custom Tabs Service.
     *
     * @param connectionCallback
     */
    public void setConnectionCallback(ConnectionCallback connectionCallback) {
        this.mConnectionCallback = connectionCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Binds the Activity to the Custom Tabs Service.
     *
     * @param activity the activity to be binded to the service.
     */
    public void bindCustomTabsService(Activity activity) {
        if (mClient != null) return;

        String packageName = CustomTabsHelper.getPackageNameToUse(activity);
        if (packageName == null) return;

        mConnection = new ServiceConnection(this);
        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(activity, packageName, mConnection);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if call to mayLaunchUrl was accepted.
     * @see {@link CustomTabsSession#mayLaunchUrl(Uri, Bundle, List)}.
     */
    public boolean mayLaunchUrl(Uri uri, Bundle extras, List<Bundle> otherLikelyBundles) {
        if (mClient == null) return false;

        CustomTabsSession session = getSession();
        if (session == null) return false;

        return session.mayLaunchUrl(uri, extras, otherLikelyBundles);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(CustomTabsClient client) {
        mClient = client;
        mClient.warmup(0L);
        if (mConnectionCallback != null) mConnectionCallback.onCustomTabsConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected() {
        mClient = null;
        mCustomTabsSession = null;
        if (mConnectionCallback != null) mConnectionCallback.onCustomTabsDisconnected();
    }

    /**
     * A Callback for when the service is connected or disconnected. Use those callbacks to
     * handle UI changes when the service is connected or disconnected.
     */
    public interface ConnectionCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the service is connected.
         */
        void onCustomTabsConnected();

        /**
         * Called when the service is disconnected.
         */
        void onCustomTabsDisconnected();
    }

    /**
     * To be used as a fallback to open the Uri when Custom Tabs is not available.
     */
    public interface CustomTabFallback {
        /**
         * @param activity The Activity that wants to open the Uri.
         * @param uri      The uri to be opened by the fallback.
         */
        void openUri(Activity activity, Uri uri);
    }

}
```

**CustomTabsHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Helper class for Custom Tabs.
 */
public class CustomTabsHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomTabsHelper";
    static final String STABLE_PACKAGE = "com.android.chrome";
    static final String BETA_PACKAGE = "com.chrome.beta";
    static final String DEV_PACKAGE = "com.chrome.dev";
    static final String LOCAL_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.apps.chrome";
    private static final String EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_KEEP_ALIVE =
            "android.support.customtabs.extra.KEEP_ALIVE";
    private static final String ACTION_CUSTOM_TABS_CONNECTION =
            "android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService";

    private static String sPackageNameToUse;

    private CustomTabsHelper() {}

    public static void addKeepAliveExtra(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent keepAliveIntent = new Intent().setClassName(
                context.getPackageName(), KeepAliveService.class.getCanonicalName());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_KEEP_ALIVE, keepAliveIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Goes through all apps that handle VIEW intents and have a warmup service. Picks
     * the one chosen by the user if there is one, otherwise makes a best effort to return a
     * valid package name.
     *
     * This is <strong>not</strong> threadsafe.
     *
     * @param context {@link Context} to use for accessing {@link PackageManager}.
     * @return The package name recommended to use for connecting to custom tabs related components.
     */
    public static String getPackageNameToUse(Context context) {
        if (sPackageNameToUse != null) return sPackageNameToUse;

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        // Get default VIEW intent handler.
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
        ResolveInfo defaultViewHandlerInfo = pm.resolveActivity(activityIntent, 0);
        String defaultViewHandlerPackageName = null;
        if (defaultViewHandlerInfo != null) {
            defaultViewHandlerPackageName = defaultViewHandlerInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        }

        // Get all apps that can handle VIEW intents.
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedActivityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, 0);
        List<String> packagesSupportingCustomTabs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ResolveInfo info : resolvedActivityList) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_CUSTOM_TABS_CONNECTION);
            serviceIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (pm.resolveService(serviceIntent, 0) != null) {
                packagesSupportingCustomTabs.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }

        // Now packagesSupportingCustomTabs contains all apps that can handle both VIEW intents
        // and service calls.
        if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.isEmpty()) {
            sPackageNameToUse = null;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.size() == 1) {
            sPackageNameToUse = packagesSupportingCustomTabs.get(0);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultViewHandlerPackageName)
                && !hasSpecializedHandlerIntents(context, activityIntent)
                && packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(defaultViewHandlerPackageName)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = defaultViewHandlerPackageName;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(STABLE_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = STABLE_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(BETA_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = BETA_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(DEV_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = DEV_PACKAGE;
        } else if (packagesSupportingCustomTabs.contains(LOCAL_PACKAGE)) {
            sPackageNameToUse = LOCAL_PACKAGE;
        }
        return sPackageNameToUse;
    }

    /**
     * Used to check whether there is a specialized handler for a given intent.
     * @param intent The intent to check with.
     * @return Whether there is a specialized handler for the given intent.
     */
    private static boolean hasSpecializedHandlerIntents(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> handlers = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    intent,
                    PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
            if (handlers == null || handlers.size() == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : handlers) {
                IntentFilter filter = resolveInfo.filter;
                if (filter == null) continue;
                if (filter.countDataAuthorities() == 0 || filter.countDataPaths() == 0) continue;
                if (resolveInfo.activityInfo == null) continue;
                return true;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Runtime exception while getting specialized handlers");
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return All possible chrome package names that provide custom tabs feature.
     */
    public static String[] getPackages() {
        return new String[]{"", STABLE_PACKAGE, BETA_PACKAGE, DEV_PACKAGE, LOCAL_PACKAGE};
    }
}
```

**ServiceConnection.java**

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

/**
 * Implementation for the CustomTabsServiceConnection that avoids leaking the
 * ServiceConnectionCallback
 */
public class ServiceConnection extends CustomTabsServiceConnection {
    // A weak reference to the ServiceConnectionCallback to avoid leaking it.
    private WeakReference<ServiceConnectionCallback> mConnectionCallback;

    public ServiceConnection(ServiceConnectionCallback connectionCallback) {
        mConnectionCallback = new WeakReference<>(connectionCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName name, CustomTabsClient client) {
        ServiceConnectionCallback connectionCallback = mConnectionCallback.get();
        if (connectionCallback != null) connectionCallback.onServiceConnected(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        ServiceConnectionCallback connectionCallback = mConnectionCallback.get();
        if (connectionCallback != null) connectionCallback.onServiceDisconnected();
    }
}
```

**ServiceConnectionCallback.java**

```
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient;

/**
 * Callback for events when connecting and disconnecting from Custom Tabs Service.
 */
public interface ServiceConnectionCallback {
    /**
     * Called when the service is connected.
     * @param client a CustomTabsClient
     */
    void onServiceConnected(CustomTabsClient client);

    /**
     * Called when the service is disconnected.
     */
    void onServiceDisconnected();
}
```

**WebviewFallback.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * A Fallback that opens a Webview when Custom Tabs is not available
 */
public class WebviewFallback implements CustomTabActivityHelper.CustomTabFallback {
    @Override
    public void openUri(Activity activity, Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, WebviewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.EXTRA_URL, uri.toString());
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

By now, you should be able to open Chrome custom tab.

If found any issue with this, just let me know.

Comment: @ValentinoS. Glad it helped.. !!

Comment: If it's possibile, I ask you the following question: I have the need to intercept some internal links to the website open with chrome custom tabs, there is a way to intercept them?

Comment: @ValentinoS. Check out the "Handle internal links" section of this guide: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem, I mean: I was trying to intercept internal links of the website opened through custom tabs. I've found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160635/check-which-url-is-opened-in-custom-chrome-tabs) so i think there is no way at today to solve this issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: It might happen that in openCustomTab method of CustomTabActivityHelper the packageName won't be null but an ActivityNotFoundException might be thrown. To reproduce this just disable Chrome on the user phone meanwhile the application is in background and then resume the application. Catching the exception and calling the fallback is a good idea! @ChintanSoni

Answer (score 1):

@Chintan Soni's answer is absolutely correct for Android SDK versions lower than 21.
For higher versions when querying activities that can handle the intent in *getPackageNameToUse()* function pass flag *PackageManager.MATCH_ALL* like this.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        resolvedActivityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
    else
        resolvedActivityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

add next string to tour code before **WebSettings webSettings**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```