# Check which url is opened in custom chrome tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there any function in chrome custom tabs analogous to onPageStarted of Webview. IN onNavigation.. the bundle is always null

Answer (score 3):

By design this is not possible with Chrome Custom Tabs. You can tell that a user has navigated but you can't tell where they've gone to. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsCallback.html for details of what's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what URL is currently open in Chrome Custom Tabs if you can get the user to trigger a PendingIntent by clicking on a toolbar action button or a menu option.

In your fragment/activity, create a nested BroadcastReceiver class that will handle the incoming intent in it's onReceive() method:

```
class DigBroadcastReceiver() : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val uri: Uri? = intent.data
        if (uri != null) {
            Log.d("Broadcast URL",uri.toString())
            main.genericToast(uri.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Add the receiver to your manifest file:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ui.dig.DigTabs$DigBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Create the PendingIntent and add it to your CustomTabsIntent.Builder:

```
val sendLinkIntent = Intent(main,DigBroadcastReceiver()::class.java)
        sendLinkIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"This is the link you were exploring")
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(main,0,sendLinkIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        // Set the action button
        AppCompatResources.getDrawable(main, R.drawable.close_icon)?.let {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(it, Color.WHITE)
            builder.setActionButton(it.toBitmap(),"Add this link to your dig",pendingIntent,false)
        }
        val customTabsIntent: CustomTabsIntent = builder.build()
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(main, Uri.parse(url))
```

See my [article explaining this on Medium](https://medium.com/@jtmuller5_98869/retrieving-the-url-from-custom-tabs-in-android-29154b992a9d).

Comment: Is it possible without a click?