# Get Loaded Url in Custom Chrome tabs when page changes

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using chrome custom tabs in my application to do authorization but I am not able to get the loaded link of chrome tab with-out using action button embedded on chrome tabs. If anyone worked on it please share their view.

I have tried making custom action button while building chrome custom tab and the action was handled using pending intent. Used below last method
[Check which url is opened in custom chrome tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160635/check-which-url-is-opened-in-custom-chrome-tabs)