# Chrome custom tabs deep link not working in jelly bean devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-support-library, chrome-custom-tabs

Following is my code for opening web url in app using chrome custom tabs

```
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.appthemecolor));
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.enableUrlBarHiding().build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
```

This code is working on Marshmellow and above devices and deep links are also working asking to open other apps but chrome custom tabs deep links not working on jelly bean devices.

Any reason why?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328814/android-open-chrome-custom-tab-from-fragment ?

Comment: No I am referring to this documentation which is saying to just add those few lines https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: I faced the same problem because my Chrome browser was not updated. Please check that. Although there should be a fallback 'WebViewActivity' that can handle these issues including Chrome browser unavailability. The above link address the same issue.

Comment: chrome brwoser is available in my device and is updated as well'

Comment: @amodkanthe any resolution on this?