# how to make in app browser in android studio to open link directly

Tags: java, android, browser, inappbrowser

how to make in app browser in android studio to open link directly like twitter and instagram.I tried below method which is not giving the desired out come.

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

this feature is called Chrome Custom Tabs, check out some [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/using-custom-chrome-tabs-in-your-android-app-b31e4f8f5194) how to implement

for gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

code implementation:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().launchUrl(context, uri);
```

Comment: this only works if a user has chrome available on their device though, right ?

Comment: afaik yes, you can detect that with some `ActivityNotFoundException` implementation (in which dev may open e.g. own `Activity` with `WebView`). more info in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864029/android-chrome-custom-tabs-fallback)